# error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' on laptop acer multimate 2350

Tags: lubuntu

> I try to install "Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver) 32bits" on a USB disk on an old laptop Acer travelmate 2350.
> My steps to install:
>
> > Create a bootable USB stick on Lubuntu
> > Startup laptop with USB stick
> > In the menu select Install Lubuntu
> > Plug a HDD 320GB connected via USB
> > select the HDD as the destination for the installation of Lubuntu.
> > Select one partition ext4 mounted to /

> The installation finished successfully.

> When a boot with the HDD connected via USB the i get the following error:
> error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
> Entering rescue mode
> grub rescue>

> I tried
>
> > grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos1)
> > grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
> > grub rescue > insmod normal

> Then i get again: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

> I tried also other linux distributions, but i get always thew same issue.

> Could you help me ?
>
> > Is my laptop Acer travelmate 2350 too old to install lubuntu 32 bits?
> >
> > > > Thanks for help.

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: Given the error message you provided; I'd check the health of your drive (using its SMART capabilities) & double check your ISO was 100% perfect & media correct, as your issue implies bad hardware OR corrupted data as I scanned it quickly; 18.04 reaches EOSS in April 2023 you realize; ie. your intention is a month of partially supported product I gather.

Comment: I have connected via USB the same HDD to an other laptop (sony vaio vgn-cr21z/r also an old laptop) and i booted successfully.

Comment: For my understanding this prouve that the installation on the HDD disk is okay.

Comment: I now that this version of Lubuntu is older, my goal is to have a linux system installed on this acer laptop.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved my issue.

I installed Lubuntu on the internal disk HDD (ide) and i could boot successfully.

My remarks: Booting from an HDD connected via USB on this model Acer multimate 2350 fails.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can't give more information as i have done. In summary: I tried to install Lubuntu on an external disk, the installation terminated successfully but i could not boot from the external disk. Then i installed Lubuntu on the internal disk and i could boot successfully. My help on this issue is: You cannot boot on this laptop from an external disk!